# Is there a desktop application for easy photo effects, like Camera+ for the iPhone?

Tags: software, post-processing, image-manipulation, photo-editing

I'm searching a desktop equivalent of the [Camera+ iPhone app](http://campl.us/). The app Camera+ has predefined effects which can be added to images. Basically, all I want is a desktop application which is able to **easily** apply numerous effects on photos/images.

I've got Adobe Photoshop, but it takes to much time to edit all the photos I have. With Camera+, nice effects can be applied within seconds so I'm searching for something like that.

I hope someone knows a good desktop application for my needs.

Comment: I am glad to see I am not the only one who asks questions about the iPhone here.

Comment: It's not a question about the iphone;), it's about a desktop equivalent and definetily is about photography. To all others, I've voted up your answers, they were all very helpfull!

Comment: Yea, that made almost no sense. It has the word "iPhone" in the title, and description, thus it is about "the iPhone".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most of that sort of functionality is incorporated into Photoshop plugins, many of which are also available for use as stand-alone applications (with a lightweight plug-in "host"). Topaz Labs, Nik Software and Alien Skin (among others) can probably provide what you're looking for.

Comment: Plugins for the win.

Comment: Thx for your answer, can't vote up yet (unfortunately)

Answer (score 2):

I think your emphasis on a **desktop application** is somewhat flawed. I would point you to **online photo editing** options such as [**Befunky**](http://www.befunky.com/) and [Fotoflexer](http://fotoflexer.com/). Many more exist, but the one I am most familiar with is BeFunky. It works in very much the same way as a phone application and it even has a phone based solution offering.

In today's modern browser world, many of these simple 1-click photo manipulation effects can be easily achieved using an online application rather then requiring the user to download an application.

You could also look at sites like tiltshiftmaker.com or even picnik.com.

Comment: Thx for your answer, can't vote up yet (unfortunately)

Answer (score 1):

In Adobe Lightroom you can download user made presets [(Example Presets)](http://www.flickr.com/groups/presets/discuss/72157612664073371/), and batch apply the ones you want to multiple photos.

Comment: Thx for your answer, can't vote up yet (unfortunately)

Answer (score 1):

You might want to check out [FX Photo Studio](http://www.fxphotostudioapp.com/) as it does a good job filling the void between iPhoto and Photoshop.  I am in the same position as you, and do most of my editing in Camera+ since it's so easy to quickly apply some simple effects to make a photo look nicer.

Answer (score -2):

there are several applications that you can use, most cost money but this one [Easy Photo Effects](http://easyphotoeffects.com/) is free. It can convert your photo's to black and white and add all sorts of interresting effects!

Comment: Hi John. Welcome to Stack Exchange. We appreciate contributions from people associated with companies, but please disclose that affiliation in your answer.