# What post processing software has a good collection of presets included?

Tags: software, post-processing

Using any program (not just Photoshop or Lightroom, they are fine, but maybe others have the right solution for me) is it possible to have nice presets out of the box?

For example instagram has some presets, that quickly give an "artistic"/creative feeling to the picture without the need to loose big time in post processing, toning, color correction, etc.

- Is there any tool to do the same on a PC?
- If I decide to do it myself is there a way to save such presets in Photoshop?

Comment: Honestly I do not see why I'm getting down voted. If you do it, please add a comment.

Comment: A quick google search for either "post processing presets"or "instagram pc" will give you _zillions_ of relevant results. As will "photoshop save presets". Please demonstrate a little effort before asking people to put in effort for you!

Comment: We already have this question, basically identical - just asking about Camera+ and not Instagram, but the same answers apply - http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/13939/is-there-a-desktop-application-for-easy-photo-effects-like-camera-for-the-ipho

Comment: @mattdm Google search provides for sure some results for "instagram pc" as it provides results for "blue automatic sausage" (even more for this than for instagram pc), but they are not very relevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you're looking for is repeatable cookie-cutter post processing recipes. I think the reason you're down voted is that it's not the best approach for post processing. Still, everyone's needs are different.

Some programs you might look into:

SnapSeed from Nik Software: http://www.snapseed.com/

Perfect Effects from onOne: http://www.ononesoftware.com/products/suite/perfect-effects/?ind

Google recently bought Picnik which might be an option for you (I believe you'll have to join Google+, though)

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried [Picasa](http://support.google.com/picasa/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=93773)? It's free, with many new presets (and [effects](http://support.google.com/picasa/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=156342)) are included in the latest version. Many effects can be applied with just one click.

Note, Picasa (just like Lightroom) does not modify the original file, so if you want to use files outside Picasa, you have to either force save or export pictures.

Answer (score 0):

Lightroom comes with presets out of the box
- B&W conversions
- Vignettes and grain
- Curves, autotone, sharpening
- vintage effects, toning, bleach bypass etc.

For photoshop, you can purchase plugins, or you can download "actions", many of which are free.  If you create your own effects, you can record them as actions.

So search here or elsewhere for Lightroom presets or Photoshop actions.